# Complex mysql update based on two fields and 'most' criteria?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

```
update employee as a 
      set a.sup_role=(
                    select b.job_role from employee as b 
                           where b.supervisorid=a.employeeid 
                           group by b.job_role 
                           order by count(b.job_role) desc 
                           limit 1
                     ) 
       where a.job_role='MAN1';
```

OK I have a table of all of our employees - around 100K.

All of our users have job roles that I built based on their employee.job_title.  So based on 4K+ job_titles I knock that down to about 40 job_roles.  This is so we can assign things in our CMS based on employee.job_roles.  This has been working good but the problem is with the managers.  The managers get some generic corporate job_title that we role into a generic job_role.

What you see above is code that I use to kind of do what I need to do - find out what job_role a supervisor based on what "most of their employees do".  This outputs the correct sup_role but there are several things wrong with my code:

- based on my syntax it won't let me update the employee table directly.  I have have to update an employee "helper" table and fill in later.
- So it is parsing through for the job_role "MAN1".  First I don't want to update this to add new manager job roles.  Also this doesn't account for my company doing ad hoc things like a manager just have a regular job title or different NULL fields.
- And then the last part is that this code is taking 6 minutes to go through.  Luckily I run this as a batch job but I am afraid it might cause crashes.

So I have the following table -

> employee
>
> with applicable fields
>
> employeeid
>
> supervisorid
>
> job_title
>
> job_role
>
> sup_role

So below is my last attempt.  It just runs and never outputs anything.  I am wondering if I need to create a helper table to grab the DISTINCT supervisorid's since one employee could be many people's supervisor.

```
update employee as a 
      set a.sup_role=(
                    select b.job_role from employee as b 
                           where b.supervisorid=a.employeeid 
                           group by b.job_role 
                           order by count(b.job_role) desc 
                           limit 1
                     ) 
      WHERE a.uid IN (select DISTINCT employee.supervisorid
                                    from employee
                                    where employee.supervisorid is not null
                                   );
```

Comment: Fix your data structure so supervisors have their own table.  This will greatly simplify the queries that you need to run.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Given that I have table "supervisors" am I running the most efficient update to get the "sup_role" updated?

Comment: . . `sup_role` would be in `supervisors` not `employees`, so I don't see the relevance to the queries in your question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - The supervisor has a "job_role" which would be something like MAN1 or MAN2 or DIRECTOR or VP.  But they would need a sup_role too so we can map them to whatever they care about.  They don't care about MAN1 stuff they might care about SALES, LAW, TECH, or whatever "most" of their employees do.

Comment: . . And that should be stored at the supervisor lever, not at the employee level.